# How to simulate mouse right-click in CodedUI tests

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mouse, coded-ui-tests, right-click

Has anyone tried to simulate a right-click in CodedUI testing?

I am trying to do:

```
Mouse.Click(note, MouseButtons.Right);
```

Where `note` is a `UITestControl`, but it shows:

> Error 16  'MouseButtons' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Input.MouseButtons' and
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons'

(I need to delete some item with the "delete" menu option on right-click)

Does it have to be simulated with a mouse event? Something like:

```
private void rightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
```

Where sender is `note`, but how to define right-click now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the class you're using:

```
Mouse.Click(note, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Input.MouseButtons.Right);
```

Otherwise, if you can remove your reference to `System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons` in the `using` section, the compiler will know which one you mean.

Comment: Did this suggestion work or did something else fix it?  If it was something else, please post the answer so others may find it, too.